# Error "Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP"

Tags: testing, networking, fabric

I am new to Fabric and I am trying to run the test network. Can anyone help me with this error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V637z.png)

I followed the steps on the official documentation and I am currently trying to run the following command:

peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile "${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem" -C mychannel -n basic --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles "${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt" --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles "${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt" -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'